# PHP - Does PDO quote safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection

```
$id  = trim((int)$_GET['id']);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' . $db->quote($id) . ' LIMIT 1';
$run = $db->query($sql)->fetch();
```

Does PDO's quote method is safe as prepared statements? Or i have to use prepared statements all the way in my script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically `quote()` is safe as prepared statements but it depends on the proper implementation of `quote()` and of course also on it's consequent usage. Additionally the implementation of the used database system/PDO driver has to be taken into account in order to answer the question.

While a prepared statement *can* be a feature of the underlying database protocol (like MySQL) and will then being "prepared" on the database server (a *server site prepare*), it does not necessarily have to be and can be parsed on client site as well (a *client site prepare*).

In PDO this depends on:

- Does the driver/database system support server side prepared statements?
- `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` must be set to `false` (default if the driver supports it)

If one of the conditions is not met, PDO falls back to *client site prepares*, using something like `quote()` under the hood again.

---

Conclusion:

Using prepared statements doesn't hurt, I would encourage you to use them. Even if you explicitly use `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` or your driver does not support server site prepares at all, prepared statements will enforce a workflow where it is safe that quoting can't be forgotten. Please check also @YourCommonSense's answer. He elaborates on that.

Answer (score 8):

Technically - yes.

However, it means that you are formatting your values **manually**. And manual formatting is always worse than prepared statements, as it makes code bloated and prone to silly mistakes and confusions.

The main problem with manual formatting - it is **detachable**. Means it can be performed somewhere  far away from the actual query execution. Where it can be forgotten, omitted, confused and such.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of using `trim` on int. And then quoting that value? Since you have integer value then use it as such

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users where id = ' . $id . ' LIMIT 1';
```

Instead of blindly quote everything just mind the types of your variables and make sure you are not doing stupid things like `$id = trim((int)$_GET['id']);` where `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];` would be more than enough

If you are not sure you can make it, use prepared statements. But please mind what you are coding